# How to configure Eclipse m2 plugin to find my enterprise repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure SpringSource Tool Suite's m2 plugin. In order to get maven to work from the command line, I had to point to our enterprise repository in the `settings.xml` file.

If I try to build inside STS, I get the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mycompany/maven/adp/adp-base-pom/1.0.14/adp-base-pom-1.0.14.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany.edelivery:edelivery-build:current 
(C:\code\workspace\edelivery-build\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact 
com.mycompany.maven.adp:adp-base-pom:pom:1.0.14 from/to central 
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): ConnectException and 'parent.relativePath' 
points at wrong local POM @ line 4, 
column 11: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I presume that I need to tell STS where the enterprise repository is, how do I do that? The only thing I find under `File -> Properties` is a field for `Active Maven Profiles` and that didn't help.

Here is a snippet from the `settings.xml` file, what do I do with this information?

```
<profile>
  <id>internal-profile</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <name>Enterprise Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://svn01g.gdc.nwie.net/maven2/enterprise</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>internal-release</id> 
      <name>MyCompany Enterprise Repository</name>
      <url>http://svn01g.gdc.nwie.net/maven2/enterprise</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using release 0.12.1 or earlier of the m2eclipse plugin, all you should have to do is point m2eclipse to your local maven installation. Choose Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations, click Add... and browse to the root of your Maven installation. Remember you need to do this again whenever you switch to a new workspace.

Answer (score 1):

The repository should be specified in the POM. Then everybody can find it.